# What is an appropriate statistical technique to use with rates of decay/growth for this estimation problem?

Tags: forecasting, survival, predictive-models, biostatistics

I have the following problem:

I have ground truth data on the population growth and the population decay of a certain breed of rabbits (let's say $R$) from $T_1$ to $T_n$.

Now, I want to estimate the population across $T_1$ to $T_n$ of a different breed of rabbits ($R'$), for which I took a sample at time $T$ (within $T_1$ and $T_n$). I don't have any reason to believe that this other breed of rabbits should be fundamentally different from breed $R$.

Can I directly compute the population at a given time knowing what I know about the growth/decay? Are there any methods that will give me confidence intervals for this type of estimation?

Finally, does the problem change in any fundamental way if I add the following layer of complexity:

Let's say I have different breeds of rabbits and I want to match parents and offspring of the same breed and I can only do so if I observe them both alive in the same sample. For every group of offspring paired to parents we have 1 family. At a given time $T$, I was able to match $X\%$ of parents/offspring of the same breed (for now, we assume that matching was similar across breeds), and so I was able to count $A$ families.

The older the rabbits are, though, the harder it is to match them (since their parents are no longer alive) but I want to have an idea of how many families there were at time $T-1, T-2, ..., T_1$, given my sample at time $T$ and what I know about the rate of decay/growth. I also would like to estimate the number of families at time $T+1, T+2, ..., T_n$.

How would I approach this problem? What kind of analyses could I use to do this estimation?